# use data of table in R

Tags: r, dataset, poisson-distribution, parameterization

I have a table of data that I have already imported in R as variable `Dataset` and I want to apply the function `fitdistr()` to my column `timeSec` with `"poisson"` option, but I do not know how extract my data.

So I tried this:

```
Myparms <- fitdistr(timeSec.Dataset, "poisson")
```

the error was:

```
Error in fitdistr(timeSec.Dataset, "poisson") :
  objet 'timeSec.Dataset' introuvable
```

I just begin to use R, so I am grateful for any help.

Comment: Please provide some kind of minimum example. The simplest problem I see here is the names timeSec.Dataset" and "dureediff_sec:dataset" do not even match and therefore it cannot be found by R.

Comment: yes, you're right, I just change it here to be clear and simple, and I forgot to change it in all msg

Comment: please, revise my message I had make some changes. thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the data extraction in R. To extract the column named  "timeSec" from the data.frame  "Dataset" you have to use either

```
  Dataset$timeSec
```

or

```
   Dataset[,"timeSec"]
```

Both R commands do the same thing.

Comment: You're welcome. That's a typical problem for "R newbies".